# last id in order

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, function

I have this data.

- Column A is line number
- Column B is reference for parent(A).

There are two groups.

- 0 in column b means new group and A is top element.

**How can I find max A from each group ?**

Lets say:

if I select  A=3 fuction should return  4,
or if I select A=6 function should return 8

```
a | b
------
1 | 0    <- for A = 1  return  4
2 | 1    <- for A = 2  return  4
3 | 2    <- for A = 3  return  4
4 | 3    <- for A = 4  return  4 
5 | 0    <- for A = 5  return  8
6 | 5    <- for A = 6  return  8
7 | 5    <- for A = 7  return  8
8 | 7    <- for A = 8  return  8
9 | 0
```

Comment: what if two groups have the same `max` value? also tag the database being used.

Comment: hi tag has been updated :-) Each group has only one max ID, doesnt matter if thes two group will have same max id.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on exactly what the function is supposed to do?  I'm not following what is going on.

Comment: Do you want the value with the highest "a" value, or the value that is the deepest down the tree? For instance, if you have the couples (9,0),(10,9),(11,10), and (12,9), what should A=9 return?

Comment: I'm still not following why `A=6` returns `8`...

Comment: @Siyual the data represents a Tree, `A` is a node, `B` its parent (with 0 meaning top level). OP wants to find the deepest (or rightmost?) child of a given node.

Comment: table updated which result expecting.  0 in column B means new group.

Comment: @JulienBlanchard Oh, I see now - that makes more sense.  I was originally thinking it should have been 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I get it.  Order matters, and you want to play [Cliffhangers](http://priceisright.wikia.com/wiki/Cliff_Hangers).  This would be a fantastic application of the [LEAD()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) function if you were on SQL Server 2012 or higher, but you tagged 2008, so... damn.

So, no `LEAD()`, but we still have options.  Here's a function that jumps into your table at a given starting point, then just starts racing forward, keeping track of the last "good" value before you fall off the cliff (encounter the next zero), then returns that last "good" value after you fall off.

Here's the table creation...

```
CREATE TABLE YourABTable (a int NOT NULL, b int NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO YourABTable (a, b) VALUES (1, 0)
INSERT INTO YourABTable (a, b) VALUES (2, 1)
INSERT INTO YourABTable (a, b) VALUES (3, 2)
INSERT INTO YourABTable (a, b) VALUES (4, 3)
INSERT INTO YourABTable (a, b) VALUES (5, 0)
INSERT INTO YourABTable (a, b) VALUES (6, 5)
INSERT INTO YourABTable (a, b) VALUES (7, 5)
INSERT INTO YourABTable (a, b) VALUES (8, 7)
INSERT INTO YourABTable (a, b) VALUES (9, 0)

GO;
```

Here's the actual function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetMaxA(@InputA int) RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE SearchCursor CURSOR 
        LOCAL 
        FORWARD_ONLY 
        FAST_FORWARD 
        READ_ONLY 
    FOR
        SELECT 
            a, 
            b 
        FROM 
            YourABTable 
        WHERE 
            a >= @InputA
        ORDER BY
            a ASC

    DECLARE @CurrentA int
    DECLARE @CurrentB int

    DECLARE @ReturnA int

    SET @CurrentA = -1
    SET @CurrentB = -1

    SET @ReturnA = @CurrentA

    OPEN SearchCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM SearchCursor 
    INTO @CurrentA, @CurrentB

    --if you want to see where you start
    --PRINT '@CurrentA = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @CurrentA)
    --PRINT '@CurrentB = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @CurrentB)

    IF @CurrentB = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @CurrentB = 1
            --cheat to get the WHILE loop running at least once if you bingo a row where B = 0 on your input
        END

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND @CurrentB > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @ReturnA = @CurrentA

        FETCH NEXT FROM SearchCursor 
        INTO @CurrentA, @CurrentB
    END 

    CLOSE SearchCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE SearchCursor ;

    RETURN @ReturnA
END;
```

Worth note: `LEAD()` isn't magic, and you can emulate it in other versions of SQL.  You do so by joining the table onto itself (a self join), joining on a key offset (i.e. table1.key = table2.key + 1), but to do that proper you'd have to use `ROW_NUMBER` as a derived temp key within your recordset.  That's because you are not guaranteed that no rows have been deleted, which would leave gaps in your column `a` sequence, which would break such a join.  It would be a perfectly valid approach, but for simplicity I prefer the above method.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joe,  It's what I exactly need.